# Good source of reviews of CULV machines?

Tags: laptop, netbook, resources, review

I'm potentially interested in acquiring a CULV machine. I like the idea of a netbook, but need a little more horsepower. So, of course, I need to obsess over a hundred different reviews first.

Can you recommend some good sources of CULV reviews? [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/mobile/showdoc.aspx?i=3735) recently ran a roundup, but I'd prefer sites that have ongoing CULV coverage. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quite strongly favour AnandTech’s reviews, and the [link you posted](http://www.anandtech.com/mobile/showdoc.aspx?i=3735&p=1) is the best CULV-notebook round-up I’ve seen. If you are looking for slightly more up to date information, then [Engadget’s CULV tag](http://www.engadget.com/tag/CULV), [TechRadar](http://www.techradar.com/search/results?searchterm=culv&datem=&datey=&show=&sort=date), [TrustedReviews](http://www.trustedreviews.com/search?q=culv&s=Search&t=1&sec=0&o=2), and [Geek.com](http://www.geek.com/articles/tagged/culv/) all provide news and reviews. [HandsOn Reviews](http://www.handsonreviews.net/tag/intel-culv/) aggregates reviews from [Notebookcheck](http://www.notebookcheck.net/) (and other sites), which I have found to be useful in the past. The Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Ultra-Low_Voltage) also has a list of current CULV-notebook which looks fairly comprehensive.